# Error: Cannot find module './lib/source-map-generator'

Tags: npm-start

I just cloned a repository ( a React Native project) from Github, ran `npm install` and then `npm start`.

Then instead of running the metro bundler, it throws the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/source-map-generator'
Require stack:
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\snapdragon\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\utils.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\snapdragon\lib\compiler.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\snapdragon\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\sane\node_modules\braces\lib\braces.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\sane\node_modules\braces\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\sane\node_modules\micromatch\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\sane\node_modules\anymatch\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\sane\src\common.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\lib\WatchmanWatcher.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro-core\src\errors\AmbiguousModuleResolutionError.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro-core\src\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\metro\src\shared\output\bundle.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\buildBundle.js   
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\bundle.js        
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\bundle\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js   
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- D:\ProjectX\node_modules\react-native\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ProjectX\node_modules\snapdragon\node_modules\source-map\source-map.js:6:30) 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\snapdragon\\node_modules\\source-map\\source-map.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\snapdragon\\lib\\utils.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\snapdragon\\lib\\compiler.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\snapdragon\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\sane\\node_modules\\braces\\lib\\braces.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\sane\\node_modules\\braces\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\sane\\node_modules\\micromatch\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\sane\\node_modules\\anymatch\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\sane\\src\\common.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\jest-haste-map\\build\\lib\\WatchmanWatcher.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\jest-haste-map\\build\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro-core\\src\\errors\\AmbiguousModuleResolutionError.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro-core\\src\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\Bundler.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\IncrementalBundler.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\Server.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\shared\\output\\bundle.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\buildBundle.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\bundle.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\bundle\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\commands\\index.js',  
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli-plugin-metro\\build\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\react-native\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\commands\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\react-native\\node_modules\\@react-native-community\\cli\\build\\index.js',
    'D:\\ProjectX\\node_modules\\react-native\\cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the Git tag?

Comment: `npm install source-map`

Comment: Anybody knows why this happened? (out of curiosity). It happened to me with Angular. Hadn't touched the project in a few days (while still serving it) and out of nowhere this happened...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing `node_modules` and repeat the npm install or yarn.

If that still doesn’t work, maybe try removing package-lock.json/yarn.lock and repeat the above.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install source-map` worked for me (as per @Muhammad Zakaria's comment above). I had this error with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted the node_modules and package.lock.json, after that I have done the `npm install` and it resolved the issue for me.